# Expected value of number of heads in n flips

Tags: probability

We flip a coin n times and calculate the number of heads. for the obtained number of heads of the previous n tosses we will toss the coin again. what is the expected value of heads in this tossing process?

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you gotten stuck?

Comment: How we can calculate this expected value after tossing for the obtained number of heads of the previous n tosses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H_1$ be the number of head in the first $n$ tosses, and $H_2$ be the number of head in the second. We are looking to compute $E(T)$, where $T=H_1 + H_2$. Note that $E
(T)=E(H_1)+E(H_2)$. $E(H_1)$ is simply $n*0.5 = n/2$. To compute $H_2$, we will use the law of total expectation, 
\begin{align}
E(H_2) = E(E(H_2|H_1)) &=\sum_{i=0}^n E(H_2|H_1=i)P(H_1=i) \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n i/2 \binom{n}{i}(0.5)^n \\
&= (0.5)^{n+1}n2^{n-1}\\
&= n/4
\end{align}
Thus, $E(T)=n/2+n/4 = 3n/4$

Comment: +1 More concise: $\mathbb E[\mathbb E[H_2\mid H_1]]=\mathbb E\frac12H_1=\frac14n$